# Getting NativeErrorCode from an System.Exception?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity

How do I get the native error code from a System.Exception?
To be more specific, i'm catching an EntityException and i need to check if it is 
"25028 SSCE_M_INVALIDPASSWORD The specified password does not match the database password."

The inner exception of my EntityException is a SqlCeException that says "The specified password does not match the database password." and that one i have to explicitly catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SqlCeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fze0ff3.aspx) has a [NativeError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceexception.nativeerror.aspx) property, so once you catch this exception look at the value of this property:

```
catch (EntityException ex)
{
    var sqlCeEx = ex.InnerException as SqlCeException;
    if (sqlCeEx != null)
    {
        var nativeError = sqlCeEx.NativeError;
        // Do something with the native error
    }
}
```